# Cardinality of possibilities to distribute 4 children to two pods?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$4$ children have to be distributed to two pods of a big wheel. 
Each pod has capacity for $3$ person.

**Question**: How many possibilities are there to distribute the $4$ children to the pods?

My Idea was $|S_{4,3}|= \displaystyle \left\{ {4 \atop 3}\right\}=6$, where $S_4$ is a permutation of a symmetric group with $3$ cycles and $\displaystyle \left\{ {4 \atop 3}\right\}$ a stirling number of second kind.

Unfortunately this is wrong. The correct answer should be $7$.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Two cases: one pod gets one child and the other gets three  or  both pods get two children each.  In the first case, choose who the lonely child is.  There are four such possibilities.  In the second case, pick who will ride with the youngest child.  There are three such possibilities.  Adding we get $4+3=7$.  Note in the second case we counted that way instead of $\binom{4}{2}$ because this is specified to be a wheel we can assume rotations to be equivalent.

Comment: The answer of $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}4\\3\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ would be for four children, three pods, and no pod empty while arrangement of the pods doesn't matter (*like a teacup ride instead of a ferris wheel*), note: an easier way to count that scenario is to simply pick which two children are together in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either both pods contain $2$ children, or one contains $3$ and the other contains $1$.

If both contain $2$ children, there are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to determine which children go in the first pod, and the other two must go in the second. However, as the pods are on a wheel they are indistinguishable - if you rotate the wheel $180$ degrees, that configuration should be considered the same. So we must divide by $2$ to account for the fact that the division $(12)(34)$ is the same as $(34)(12)$ and so on. Thus there are $3$ ways to put $2$ children in each pod.

If one pod contains $3$ children and the other contains $1$, there are just $4$ possibilities - simply choose the $1$ child out of the $4$ that will be alone. We do not need to consider which pod the child is in, because as stated above the pods are indistinguishable.

Thus we get $3+4=7$ configurations.